# What are the advantages / disadvantages of off-policy RL vs on-policy RL?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, q-learning

There are various algorithms for reinforcment learning (RL). One way to group them is by "off-policy" and "on-policy". I've heard that SARSA is on-policy, while Q-Learning is off-policy.

I think they work as follows:

[image]

[image]

My questions are:

- How exactly is "on-policy RL" and "off-policy RL" defined?
- What are the advantages / disadvantages of both?

Comment: Please also let me know if there is an error in my pseudocode

Comment: I think a good place to start to understand this would be this recent paper : http://jmlr.org/proceedings/papers/v32/silver14.pdf

Answer (score 4):

This was answered in [cross-validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/184657/difference-between-off-policy-and-on-policy-learning) and [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6848828/674487):

> The reason that Q-learning is off-policy is that it updates its Q-values using the Q-value of the next state $s′$ and the greedy action $a′$. In other words, it estimates the return (total discounted future reward) for state-action pairs assuming a greedy policy were followed despite the fact that it's not following a greedy policy.
>
> The reason that SARSA is on-policy is that it updates its Q-values using the Q-value of the next state $s′$ and the current policy's action $a′′$. It estimates the return for state-action pairs assuming the current policy continues to be followed.

[These slides](http://www.inf.ed.ac.uk/teaching/courses/rl/slides15/rl05.pdf) offer some insight on pros and cons of each one:

- On-policy methods:

  - attempt to evaluate or improve the policy that is used to make decisions,
  - often use soft action choice, i.e. $\pi(s,a) >0,  \forall a$,
  - commit to always exploring and try to find the best policy that still explores,
  - may become trapped in local minima.
- Off-policy methods:

  - evaluate one policy while following another, e.g. tries to evaluate the greedy policy while following a more exploratory scheme,
  - the policy used for behaviour should be soft,
  - policies may not be sufficiently similar,
  - may be slower (only the part after the last exploration is reliable), but remains more flexible if alternative routes appear.

For reference, these are the formulations of Q-learning and SARSA from [Sutton and Barto seminal book](https://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/%7Esutton/book/ebook/the-book.html):

- [Q-learning](https://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/%7Esutton/book/ebook/node65.html):

[image: Q-learning algorithm]

- [SARSA](http://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/%7Esutton/book/ebook/node64.html):

[image: SARSA algorithm]

P.S.: I referenced and quoted the original answer from a different stackexchange site, as indicated in [this meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/172309/174973).